# VisualStudio CI Build from GIT

Tags: cordova, azure-devops, visual-studio-cordova, azure-pipelines

I have a git repository which contains one folder which I want to include in CI build.

However, when I try to run [Cordova Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsclient.cordova-extension) it fails (which make sense) because in the root of my git repository is not cordova project, my project is in `XYZ` folder.

So, my question is, is it possible to make this build task to work with the source from that `XYZ` folder instead of trying to run commands in git root?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the working directory argument of the build task to

```
$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\xyz
```

[image]